# validationDefault not working CakePHP

Tags: validation, cakephp

Model/Table/TableName.php

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator){

            $validator = new Validator();
            $validator
                        ->add('email', 'minLength', [
                            'rule' => ['minLength', 50]
                        ])
                        ->add('mobile', 'validValue', [
                            'rule' => ['range', 1, 5]
                        ]);

            return $validator;
        }
```

Controller

```
$testsTable = TableRegistry::get('Tests');
$test = $testsTable->newEntity($this->request->getData());
$testsTable->save($test);
```

$test->errors() Must show error if Post data provided is:

```
Array
(
    [Test] => Array
        (
            [email] => anubhav@gmail.com
            [mobile] => 09999999998

        )

)
```

Because my validation rule says email minlength should be 50.

Please tell what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you instantiate a new Validator inside the method ?

Comment: I have instantiate a new validator hoping it will work then but invain

Comment: `TableName != TestsTable`. Please use the actual names that your code is using. Incorrect naming can cause the registry to return an auto-table.